# All third-party Audio Units are missing

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, audiounit

In my iOS AU host application, I am using AVAudioUnitComponentManager.components method to retrieve the list of available Audio Units. It works as expected most of the time. However sometimes it returns only Audio Units created by Apple, and none of the third-party Audio Units that are installed on the device. The interesting thing is that, if after I encounter this issue in my app I go to GarageBand and open the Audio Unit list there then when I return to my app, all the third-party AUs are present. So I am wondering maybe  some other initialization should be done before calling AVAudioUnitComponentManager.components method which GarageBand is doing and I also should do in my app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is turned out, the problem was happening because my app did not have an entitlements file with the “Inter-App Audio” capability key. After adding this capability to my project target in xcode the problem was fixed.